# Ways to use a raspberry pi code that measures the system (INA219) and have it ran on a separate device (Arduino Uno)?

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi3

I have a `Raspberry Pi` that is connected to a `INA219` current sensor.

It currently runs a `python` script that measures the following of the `Raspberry Pi`:

- Bus voltage & current
- Power
- Shunt voltage

This data is stored in a `CSV` file that runs 10 times per second until the user stops it (CTRL + C).

I am trying to create a script on my `Arduino` so that the script on the `Raspberry Pi` can run on a separate device, which is the `Arduino UNO`.

The code from the `Raspberry Pi` that I am trying to get to run on a separate device is attached below:

```
#Importing libraries
import csv
import time

from ina219 import INA219
from ina219 import DeviceRangeError


SHUNT_OHMS = 0.1

read_ina = INA219(SHUNT_OHMS) 
read_ina.configure()

  
def read_all():
    
    data = {}
    data['Bus Voltage'] = read_ina.voltage()
    data['Bus Current'] = read_ina.current()
    data['Power'] = read_ina.power()
    data['Shunt Voltage'] = read_ina.shunt_voltage()
    data ['Frequency'] = 0
    return data

    
with open('SensorData.csv', 'w') as f:
    data = read_all()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,
                            fieldnames = list (data.keys()))

    writer.writeheader()

    
    exit = False

    while not exit:
        try:
            writer.writerow(data)
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            data = read_all()
            compute_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
            data['Frequency'] = 1 / compute_time 
            
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit = True
```

Again, I am having a hard time with having it show on the `Arduino UNO` interface. I have the `Arduino IDE` installed on my `Raspberry Pi` and have not had luck with such this script.

I am aware that I need to create rewrite the script to `Arduino C++`. I am having a problem with creating the code for the Arduino.

I don't have a breadboard or `HDMI` for the `Arduino` (it is connected to the `Raspberry Pi`) so I am also just confused on how I get it to display on the `Arduino` if there is no interface on which it could be visibly seen on.

In terms of the code for the `Arduino`, is there a way that I can create a script (on `Arduino`) that goes into the `Raspberry Pi` system and pulls the script from the `Raspberry Pi` system instead of creating a new script?